# SQL Server Left join "With" table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a query that looks like this

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
 SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY JobID ORDER BY JobID) AS RowNbr,JobsTagMap.JobID
 FROM JobsTagMap
)
SELECT 
    *,
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + Title 
           FROM Tags
           JOIN JobsTagMap ON Tags.TagID = JobsTagMap.TagID
           WHERE JobsTagMap.JobID = CTE.JobID
           FOR XML PATH('')
          ), 1, 1, '') AS Title
FROM CTE
WHERE CTE.RowNbr = 1
```

Now, I want do something like this (above query referred to as 'my big query')

```
SELECT * FROM Jobs LEFT JOIN ('my big query') q on Jobs.JobID=q.JobID
```

But when I do so, I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking
>   context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a
>   semicolon.

How am I supposed to join such a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
;WITH Cte AS 
(
    SELECT Row_number() OVER(partition BY JobID ORDER BY JobID) AS RowNbr, 
         JobsTagMap.JobID 
    FROM JobsTagMap
), FinalCte AS
( 
    SELECT*, 
                Stuff ((SELECT ',' + Title 
                                FROM   Tags 
                                             JOIN JobsTagMap 
                                                 ON Tags.TagID = JobsTagMap.TagID 
                                WHERE  JobsTagMap.JobID = CTE.JobID 
                                FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '') AS Title 
    FROM   cte 
    WHERE  CTE.RowNbr = 1 
)
SELECT * 
    FROM Jobs LEFT JOIN FinalCte q 
        ON Jobs.JobID=q.JobID
```